# IP Address Input from Jenkins to Variable powershell

Tags: powershell, jenkins, fortigate

I Have Jenkins job that asks for IP Address

```
$ip = $env:Lan_ip
```

what the user enter goes to `$ip`

now `$ip` is 192.168.10.10 for Example

now I'm trying to insert this variable to FortiGate SSH

```
Invoke-SshCommand $Firewall -command ‘config system interface 
edit port1
set ip $ip 255.255.255.0
end’
```

but he can not read the `$ip` I need to make it like INT separate with `.`

im getting this Error

```
node_check_object fail! for ip $ip
```

how can i convert the sting im getting from the user when he enter the ip address in for example --> 192.168.10.10
to usable variable in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gather from [here](https://help.fortinet.com/fadc/4-4-0/cli/Content/FortiADC/cli-ref/config_system_interface.htm) is that you need to give the **subnet mask** as a CIDR-formatted subnet mask like `255.255.255.0/24`

To get that CIDR value off a subnet IP address, you can use this function:

```
function Get-SubnetMaskLength ([string]$SubnetMask) {
    # $cidr = Get-SubnetMaskLength "255.255.240.0" --> 20
    $result = 0
    [IPAddress]$ip = $SubnetMask
    foreach ($octet in $ip.GetAddressBytes()) {
        while ($octet) {
            $octet = ($octet -shl 1) -band [byte]::MaxValue
            $result++
        }
    }
    $result
}
```

So

```
$subNet = '255.255.255.0'
$cidr = Get-SubnetMaskLength $subNet          # --> 24
$subNetAndCidr = '{0}/{1}' -f $subNet, $cidr  # --> 255.255.255.0/24
```

<sup>P.S. Always use **straight** quotes instead of the curly thingies `‘` and `’` in code!</sup>